# SSRS Report Snapshot\Caching - Report depends on user context

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

My company has a number of reports that generate daily\weekly and email to our sales staff.  Because it's sales, we reference the current user ID for context, so the report generates differently based on the user who requested the report.  For example, if the user is domain\somemanager, the references a lookup table and see's that domain\peon1 and domain\peon2 report to somemanager.  However, if domain\peon1 requests the report, they don't see any information for domain\peon2.

We're running SSRS 2008 integrated with SharePoint 2010.  With this information, how can I perform snapshotting or report caching for each of my users (50 in total)?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in SSRS 2008 R2 (not sure about 2008) where you can use the NULL Delivery Provider in a data-driven subscription to trigger report caching using parameters. I haven't actually used this feature for any of our solutions but I have read about it. See this page: [Report Caching in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (specifically the section titled "Preloading the Cache") and you could also have a look at [Data-Driven Subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

What you can do is make the username a hidden parameter that has a default value of an expression that references that username. You can then use a data-driven subscription and the NULL Delivery Provider to preload the report cache.

Actually, I've just noticed that you have a Sharepoint integrated installation. All of our SSRS setups are standalone so I'm not sure if this will apply exactly to your setup, but I would imagine you could still use the NULL Delivery Provider and Data Driven Subscriptions so it should still work fine.